# I made this c++ program which counts the words but when the text input is more than 1 word it just gives me 18446744073709551615

Tags: c++

I am a beginner and noob to c++ and i thought to create this program which takes in user input paragraph and then a word then finds where all the word is used.

this is the code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    string user_text;
    string user_word;
    cout << "Enter the text: ";
    cin >> user_text;
    cout << "What is the word that you want to find: ";
    cin >> user_word;
    cout << user_text.find(user_word);

}
```

and it gives me this error

```
Enter the text: well Hello this is 1
What is the word that you want to find: 18446744073709551615
D:\Projects\C++\Visual Studio\WordCounter\x64\Debug\WordCounter.exe (process 20076) exited with code 0.
```

Comment: When word is not found by `.find()` it returns `std::string::npos` which is equal to `-1` which is `18446744073709551615` in 64-bit unsigned representation. So it signifies that the word wasn't found. Also `.find()` doesn't count words, but finds position (character index) of first occurance of word.

Comment: There's a big hint in the output: Note that the program didn't stop and wait for you to input the wrd to look for. This is a sign that input is not being read correctly. This is covered in Jeffery's answer, but in the general case it's something to look out for.

Answer (score 2):

`string.find()` returns a position. It returns it with type `size_t` which is unsigned.

The value you are showing is `string::npos`, which means the word was not found. The most likely reason for the word to not be found is that:

`cin >> user_text;` doesn't do what you think it does. This will read a single word. You need to use `getline` instead to read a full line and not just a single word.

Please see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline